# как записать число в 16-ричной системе прямо в коде

Tags: c#, delphi

есть строка из delphi:

```
     Result := (Result shr 1) xor (Mask and $EDB88320);
```

я смог перевести её в c# но проблема с $EDB88320 как её записать прямо в коде, как в delphi?

пробовал записать в 10-тично:

```
     result = (result >> 1) ^ (mask & 3988292384);
```

но считает не правильно

Comment: если получаешь неожиданный ответ, возможно дело не в числе `3988292384`, а в чем-то еще

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# поддерживает [шестнадцатиричные литералы](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types#integer-literals). Они начинаются с `0x`

```
0xEDB88320
```